# could not find methods android() for argument

Tags: android, gradle

I have been facing an error

```
could not find method android() for arguments [build_4xspwt8fzluqpdb5cxlxgfqys$run_closure2@4eaa98f] on root project 'Creasle' of type org.gradle.api.Project
```

My build.gradle file is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.30' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
android {
    compileSdk 31
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'
    ndkVersion '24.0.8215888'
}
```

I have tried previously stated solutions on StackOverflow and they are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use google services:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
```

Comment: Sorry, i tried but it did not work.

Comment: Try to create the project again and move the necessary files that do not affect the project